# the form which remains null symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony4, php-7

I set up a search form with a handmade Entity but the form does not transmit the info to the entity ... you have an idea to solve this problem?

Also it's symfony 4.4 and I've already checked the findWeeklyPlanningRs query in the repository and it works fine.

this is the entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity ;

class FilterWeek
{

  private $nbWeek ;


      public function getNbWeek(): ?int
      {
          return $this-> nbWeek;
      }

      public function setNbWeek(int $nbWeek): self
      {
          $this->$nbWeek = $nbWeek;

          return $this;
      }

}
```

the Controller

```
  /**
        * @Route("/{id}/week" ,  name="week")
        */

        public function weeklyPlanning(Request $request ,  $id ) : Response
        {

          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

          $week = new FilterWeek();

          $form = $this -> createForm(FilterWeekType::class , $week ) ;
          $form->handleRequest($request);





          $planning = $em -> getRepository(Chargement::class) -> findWeeklyPlanningRs($id , $week-> getNbWeek()  ) ;

          $responsableSecteur = $em ->getRepository(ResponsableSecteur::class)->find($id) ;



          return $this -> render('Planing/ResponsableSecteurWeek.html.twig' , [
            'responsable_secteur' => $responsableSecteur,
            'chargements' => $planning ,
            'form' => $form -> createView()
            ] );

        }
```

the form :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\FilterWeek;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;

class FilterWeekType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('nbWeek' , IntegerType::class , [

              'label' => 'numéro de la semaine' ,
              'required' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => FilterWeek::class,
            'method' => 'get',
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix(){

      return '';
    }
}
```

the view :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

  <div class="container">

    <h3>Planning des chargements par Semaine</h3>

    <br><br>

    <div class="form-row" >
      <div class="col-4">
        {{ form_start(form) }}
          {{ form_row(form.nbWeek) }}
            <button class="btn color-br"  style="top : 5em;" >Rechercher</button>

        {{ form_end(form) }}
      </div>
```

Comment: what is the output when you click the `Rechercher` button?

Comment: yes  Khaled Alam exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found an answer to the problem:

Explanation :

In the Controller

I had to use the request parameter ($request).
and retrieve the parameters passed in the get method :

and you have to be careful because the result of the get method is a string of characters...

```
$value = $request -> get('parameter')
```

for example in my case it looks like:

```
$nb_week = $request->get('nbWeek')
```

and since the result is a string of characters we apply the intval method so that it is an integer.

```
$nb_week = intval( $request->get('nbWeek')  ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entity is currently incomplete. It is better to use `php bin/console make:entity` to generate entity because it generates `$id` and repository automatically. Also you need annotations to denote the type of `nbWeek`. So the entity should look like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\FilterWeekRepository")
 */
class FilterWeek
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $nbWeek;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNbWeek(): ?int
    {
        return $this->nbWeek;
    }

    public function setNbWeek(int $nbWeek): self
    {
        $this->nbWeek = $nbWeek;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The code of the controller which you post is currently incomplete. But I think you need to  add the following lines under `$responsableSecteur = $em->getRepository(ResponsableSecteur::class)->find($id);`:

```
$filterWeek = new FilterWeek();
$filterWeek->setNbWeek($request->get('nbWeek'));
$em->persist($filterWeek);
$em->flush();
```

It creates the object of FilterWeek and pushes it into the database. Make sure that you have created the table in the database.

The form and template looks fine. At least, I didn't need to improve them before it started to work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but this form is not a form to send information directly to the database ... it's a search form so ... it retrieves information from another entity. 
So there's no need for MRIs, I guess.

Comment: I haven't seen other entities in the post. Sorry, but I don't know how to deal with them. It would be nice if you publish them too.

Comment: in fact there was no other entity in the problem...
in fact the Filterweek entity is a 'fake' entity to be able to create a search form on a field of another entity ... so it must not be directly linked to the database because there is no table that refers to it...